# Getting data part from JSON Array

Tags: c#, json, datatable

I have following output from JSON call in c#

```
 {"Field": [
    "PID",
    "PName"],
  "Data": [
    [
      5,
      "A3"]
    ]
    }
```

I want to get only Data part which is an array of data and to store in Data Table.That I have to do in c# so that I can manipulate it.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What JSON parsing library are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonimlf9pJcHOOBQMfg&sig2=jHoaRopmDESqVa_P52_F9A) Library,
and use following line of code

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject obj = youJsonObject;
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken data= obj.GetValue("Data");
```

You can download and install nuget package for Newtonsoft from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)

Comment: @Digambar please mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: @Digambar I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JavaScriptSerializer this will convert json to C# object/List of objects

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization
///
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var object = serializer.DeserializeObject(jsonString) as (your object type)
```

"your object type" is a class you create to represent the data converted from json this will help you  to manipulate it  easily in C#